# The set of limit points is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $E'$ be the set of all limit points of a set $E$. Prove that $E'$ is closed.

Let $z$ be a limit point of $E'$. Then for any $\varepsilon>0$ deleted neighborhood with radius $\varepsilon/2$ has common with $E'$. It means that $\exists y\in E'$ such that $0<\rho(y,z)<\varepsilon/2$.

So $y\in E'$ then $\exists x\in E$ such that $x\in N'_{\varepsilon/2}(y)$. It means that $0<\rho(y,x)<\varepsilon/2$

Applying triangle inequality: $\rho(x,z)\leqslant\rho(x,y)+\rho(y,z)<\varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2=\varepsilon$

But $\rho(x,z)$ must be $>0$. How to prove that?
It we prove that we got that $z\in E'$

Comment: For your ball centered at $y$, rather than a radius of $\varepsilon/2$, choose something smaller than $\rho(y,z)$.

Comment: And what do we get?

Comment: Then we still have $\rho(x,z)<\varepsilon$, but we also have $\rho(x,z)\geq|\rho(y,z)-\rho(x,y)|>0.$